# silence 'No such file or directory' error while using zgrep

Tags: linux, bash

Trying to silence 'No such file or directory' error while using zgrep.
It did not work with any of below options
-s, --silent , -q , --quiet, --no-messages

uname -a 
Linux ... #1 SMP Wed Jul 18 19:37:38 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Any help ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the zgrep calls gzip, however, gzip isn't silent, whereas grep is.

`zgrep bla bla`

results in:
`gzip: bla.gz: No such file or directory`
so the error comes from gzip. The options zgrep uses are passed to grep and not gzip. gzip can ignore warnings, however errors are still printed hence creating a alias gzip=`gzip -q`, doesn't really help.

What you can do is redirect the standard error stream to /dev/null

`zgrep bla bla 2> /dev/null`

This also catches the errors that gzip prints to the stderr.

Comment: sure that can be considered, but I was expecting this feature to be there inbuilt.

Comment: That seems to be a `zgrep` problem indeed, as for grep this just works. I get the message `gzip: blabla.gz: No such file or directory` So it is actually gzip that prints the error, not grep (zgrep).

Comment: @RaghavendraB I adjusted the answer to show where the error comes from.

Comment: zgrep does append .gz to /dev/null too ?
gzip: 2>/dev/null.gz: No such file or directory